# SQL Statement with weird alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a sql stored procedure I see a block of sql that looks like this:

```
SELECT @GenPlanGuid = GenPlanGuid
FROM ACM.BeeBusiness
WHERE BeeBusinessGuid = @BeeBusinessGuid
```

There is no database named ACM, no linked server, no functions, nothing that is a subselect with an alias like this --> (select something from something) ACM

So where is that alias hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be the 'schema name', sometimes referred to as 'owner name' or 'user name'.

Which DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the owner of the table. If a table name is qualified, it could be written as [dbo].[tableName], where [dob] is the name of the account that owns the table. If ACM was a user who created that table, and didn't change the owner to dbo, this could happen.